# Expanding Date Class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, expand

I added this method

```
def self.addsub(days)
    if date.year==(date+days).year
        date=date+days
    else
        date=date-354+days
    end
  return date
  end
```

To a expension of the Date class which mostly looks like this:

```
class Date
  include Holidays

  # Get holidays on the current date.
  #
  # Returns an array of hashes or nil. See Holidays#between for options
  # and the output format.
  #
  #   Date.civil('2008-01-01').holidays(:ca_)
  #   => [{:name => 'New Year\'s Day',...}]
  #
  # Also available via Holidays#on.

  def holidays(*options)
    Holidays.on(self, options)
  end
```

I try expand the holidays-gem, but I allways get this, when trying to run my method.

```
C:\...\Projekt 05.03.14\Timo\Testscripts>ruby jtt.rb
jtt.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `addsub' for #<Date: -4712-01-01 ((0j,0s,
0n),+0s,2299161j)> (NoMethodError)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
If you want to see the whole file:

you can find it at [github](https://github.com/alexdunae/holidays/blob/master/lib/holidays.rb)...

EDIT:

Thanks to [Slicedpan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1478217/slicedpan)... He told me the solution:

```
class Date
  def addsub(days)
    if self.year == (self + days).year
      self + days
    else
      self - 354 + days
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The jtt.rb script is just a short test script I wrote.

require 'holidays'

d=Date.new

d.addsub(49)

Comment: Can you add the code surrounding your `addsub` method definition?

Comment: How do you call the method `addsub`? It is defined as a class method but it seems you are calling it on a `Date` instance. What is `date` inside the `addsub` method? Where does it come from?

Comment: Also where does 354 come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `self` from the method definition to make an instance method. Also inside that method, you refer to the instance you are calling it on using `self`

```
class Date
  def addsub(days)
    if self.year == (self + days).year
      self + days
    else
      self - 354 + days
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: 354 is the length of an everage-(non-leap)-year in Hijri-Calender.

Answer (score 0):

Your error suggests you are calling `addsub` method on an instance of date, however you are defining it on a class (`def self.<name>` are class methods). Instead, try:

```
def addsub(days)
  date = if self.year == (date + days).year
    date + days
  else
    date - 354 + days
  end
  date
end
```